# How to get parent object from child object dynamically

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the parent object from a child object dynamically?  Essentially, all I'm trying to accomplish is to dynamically retrieve the value of a property belonging to a child objects' parent. For example, something along the lines of the following:

```
public T GetParentProperty<T>(object oChildObject, string sPropertyName)
{
    ??? oOwner;
    PropertyInfo oOwnerInfo;
    T oPropertyValue;

    try
    {
        oPropertyValue = null;
        if (oChildObject != null)
        {
            oOwner = oChildObject.GetType().???;
            oOwnerInfo = oOwner.GetType().GetProperty(sPropertyName);
            if (oOwnerInfo != null)
                oPropertyValue = oOwnerInfo.GetValue(oOwner, null) as T;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception oEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oEx);
    }

    return oPropertyValue;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean "Parent" as in the class that your child inherits from, you can use the BaseType property of the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Class.  If the BaseType property doesn't return exactly what you need, then you can look through the list of members at that link, and find the one that does.  This is what you code example appears to be attempting.

Unfortunately, if you mean "Parent" as in the class that owns the reference to your child type, I don't think this can be done.

I'm wondering why you need this functionality though, as it is a strange need.

Comment: By parent, I was referring to the class that owns the reference to the child object.  I was wanting to avoid having to pass a reference to the parent class and instead traverse upwards from the child object. However, since this is not possible, I accepted the approach of passing the reference to the parent class. Thanks for your help!